# Data not loaded correctly into snowflake table from S3 bucket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble loading data from an amazon S3 bucket to the snowflake table. This is my command:

```
copy into myTableName
  from 's3://dev-allocation-storage/data_feed/'
  credentials=(aws_key_id='***********' aws_secret_key='**********')
  PATTERN='.*/.*/.*/.*'
  file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' skip_header = 1 error_on_column_count_mismatch=false );
```

I have 3 CSV files in my bucket and they are all being loaded into the table. But I have 8 columns in my target table, but they are all being loaded into the first columns as a JSON object.

Comment: WHY ARE WE YELLING?

Comment: @Alexander if you approve the edit, then the yelling could stop. And then another edit to remove the not needed AWS tags could also be made.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have each row enclosed in double-quotes. Something like "f1|f2|...|f8". This will be treated like one single column value. Unlike "f1"|"f2"|...|"f8".